# UI-select в табличной строке

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Имеется следующая DOM-структура: `modalDiv (модальное окно) -> ui-grid -> ui-select`. В модальном окне находится грид, в колонке которого располагается `ui-select`.

Проблема 1: в `ui-grid` стоит свой `overflow` для строки. В связи с этим, внутренние элементы обрезаются высотой строки таблицы. Т.е. если я раскрываю `select`, то options обрезаются высотой строки. Для решения этой проблемы я добавляю директиву `append-to-body` в `ui-select`, которая закрепляет элемент в `body`. Но в этой связи позникает следующая проблема.

Проблема 2: поскольку грид находится в модальном окне, а селект закрепляется в body, то при скролле модального окна, селект располагается относительно body и скролится вместе с модалкой (как будто бы он `fixed`).

Как можно решить эту проблему? Попробовал вместо `ui-select` вставить нативный `<select>`, то проблема решается интересным приемом: блокируется скролл до тех пора, пока `select` находится в раскрытом состоянии. Но нативный селект не устраивает, т.к. его стилизовать не удобно. Возможно, можно как-то решить проблему по-другому? Если нет, то как можно блокировать скролл (не убирать overflow: hidden, т.к. будет модалка "дрожать") пока селект раскрыт и вновь включать скролл, когда селект закрыт?

Воспроизвел проблему в редакторе. Попробуйте без модалки открыть селект и поскроллить страницу, а затем откройте модалку и повторите действия. Проблема станет очевидной.

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.grid', 'ui.select', 'ui.bootstrap']);

angular
  .module('myApp')
  .controller('mainCtrl', ['$uibModal', function ($uibModal) {
    const vm = this;
    
    var myTemplate = '<ui-select-wrap>\n' +
          '    <ui-select class="my-dropdown" ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD"\n' +
          '               append-to-body="true">\n' +
          '        <ui-select-match>{{ COL_FIELD }}</ui-select-match>\n' +
          '        <ui-select-choices repeat="item in col.colDef.editDropdownOptionsArray | filter: $select.search">\n' +
          '            <span>{{ item }}</span>\n' +
          '        </ui-select-choices>\n' +
          '    </ui-select>\n' +
          '</ui-select-wrap>';
  
  vm.open = function () {
    $uibModal.open({
      template: '<h3>А теперь попробуйте тут открыть Select и поскролить :(</h3>' +
      '<div ui-grid="$ctrl.gridOptions"></div>',
      controller: 'mainCtrl',
      controllerAs: '$ctrl',
      resolve: {
        gridOptions: function () {
          return vm.gridOptions;
        }
      }
    });
  }
  
  vm.gridOptions = {
      columnDefs: [
        { name: 'status', width: '50%' },
        { 
          name: 'name',
          cellTemplate: myTemplate,
          editDropdownOptionsArray: ['John', 'Bob', 'Alice']
        }
      ],
      data: [
        { status: 'New' },
        { status: 'New' }
      ],
      rowHeight: 40
    };
  }]);
```

```css
.my-dropdown {
  z-index: 1100 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/4.6.3/ui-grid.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/4.6.3/ui-grid.core.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/4.6.3/ui-grid.edit.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-select/0.20.0/select.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-select/0.20.0/select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="mainCtrl as main">
    <button ng-click="main.open()">ОТРЫТЬ МОДАЛКУ</button>
    <h3>Здесь Select работает как нужно. Откройте селект и попробуйте проскролить окно: селект находится на месте. Теперь откройте модалку.</h3>
    <div ui-grid="main.gridOptions"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Чем вас не устраивает мой ответ? Пишите, не стесняйтесь)

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать написать свою директиву.

Потом манипулировать с селектом так, как надо.

пример:

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.grid', 'ui.select', 'ui.bootstrap']);

angular
  .module('myApp')
  .directive('uiSelectFix', function() {
    return {
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        const cell = element.parent().parent();
        // устанавливаем ширину селекта
        function setWidth(width) {
          const uiWrap = element.parent();
          uiWrap.css({
            maxWidth: width,
            minWidth: width
          });
        };
        // выносим select из ячейки, что бы overflow на него не работал
        function init() {
          const uiWrap = element.parent();
          const row = uiWrap.parent().parent();
          uiWrap.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            right: 0
          });
          row.append(uiWrap);
        };
        init();
        // Нужно для изменения размера, при ресайзе окна или родительского элемента
        scope.$watch(function() {
          return getComputedStyle(cell[0]).maxWidth;
        }, function(n, o) {
          if (n === 0)
            return;
          setWidth(n);
        })
      }
    };
  })
  .controller('mainCtrl', ['$uibModal', function($uibModal) {
    const vm = this;

    var myTemplate = '<ui-select-wrap>\n' +
      '    <ui-select ui-select-fix class="my-dropdown" ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD"\n' +
      '               >\n' +
      '        <ui-select-match>{{ COL_FIELD }}</ui-select-match>\n' +
      '        <ui-select-choices repeat="item in col.colDef.editDropdownOptionsArray | filter: $select.search">\n' +
      '            <span>{{ item }}</span>\n' +
      '        </ui-select-choices>\n' +
      '    </ui-select>\n' +
      '</ui-select-wrap>';

    vm.open = function() {
      $uibModal.open({
        template: '<h3>А теперь попробуйте тут открыть Select и поскролить :(</h3>' +
          '<div ui-grid="$ctrl.gridOptions"></div>',
        controller: 'mainCtrl',
        controllerAs: '$ctrl',
        resolve: {
          gridOptions: function() {
            return vm.gridOptions;
          }
        }
      });
    }

    vm.gridOptions = {
      columnDefs: [{
          name: 'status',
          width: '50%'
        },
        {
          name: 'name',
          cellTemplate: myTemplate,
          editDropdownOptionsArray: ['John', 'Bob', 'Alice']
        }
      ],
      data: [{
          status: 'New'
        },
        {
          status: 'New'
        }
      ],
      rowHeight: 40
    };
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/4.6.3/ui-grid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/4.6.3/ui-grid.core.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/4.6.3/ui-grid.edit.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-select/0.20.0/select.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-select/0.20.0/select.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="mainCtrl as main">
    <button ng-click="main.open()">ОТРЫТЬ МОДАЛКУ</button>
    <h3>Здесь Select работает как нужно. Откройте селект и попробуйте проскролить окно: селект находится на месте. Теперь откройте модалку.</h3>
    <div ui-grid="main.gridOptions"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```